# How to show Total No. of post In blogger with ajax get method

Tags: json, ajax, blogger

I want to show total no. of post in blogger with ajax get method bellow is my code.

```
<div id='show'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
url: "https://techtovillage.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&max-results=10&start-index=2&alt=json-in-script",
type: "get",
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function (data) {
var Posts = '<div class="hindipathtestapp">';
for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
var totalposts = json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
var posttitle = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
var postcontent = data.feed.entry[i].content.$t;
Posts += "<div class='testapp'><h1>" + totalposts + "</h1><h3>" + posttitle + "</h3><div class='content'>" + postcontent + "</div></div>";
}
Posts += "</div>"
document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = Posts;
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id='show'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://techtovillage.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        var totalposts = data.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t;
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = "<div class='totalposts'>" + totalposts + "</div>";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery in your template?

Comment: Yes, i am using<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ok forget this I will update the answer just few mins.

Comment: Try now it works fine if you want to add any text after or before number put it inside quotes